# Error being thrown due to struct literal inside function call in if statement inside a loop

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

So, I ran into an odd bug which I cannot figure out in CF9. It appears to be caused by using a struct literal, inside a function call, inside an `if` statement, inside a loop. Remove any one of these variables and the condition does not occur.

The following code throws an error:

Error: `Variable KEY is undefined.`

```
<cffunction name="test">
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>

<cfset local.data = { first = "asdf" }>

<cfloop list="first" index="key">
    <cfif test({ name = local.data[key] })>
        <cfoutput>test</cfoutput>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Why? If we set the struct to a variable it works. If we do not loop it works just fine as well.

```
<cffunction name="test">
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>

<cfset local.data = { first = "asdf" }>
<cfset key = "first">
<cfif test({ name = local.data[key] })>
    <cfoutput>test</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Any ideas what is going?

Comment: Which specific version of CF9? I think 9.0.1 or 9.0.2 fixed some issues when providing structs **inline** would not work.

Comment: Version: 9,0,1,274733, Update Level: D:/ColdFusion9/lib/updates/chf9010002.jar, Edition: Developer.

Comment: Is this incside a CFC or just a UDF function call?

Comment: The error I get:
Variable KEY is undefined.
 
The error occurred in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\stack\implicit\index.cfm: line 8

6 : 
7 : <cfloop list="first" index="key">
8 :     <cfif test({ name = local.data[key] })>
9 :         <cfoutput>test</cfoutput>
10 :     </cfif>

Works fine in CF10 though.

Comment: I can replicate on CF 9.0.2, but it's fixed in CF10. Trying to find the bug ref...

Comment: [nope, couldn't find it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a better answer once you give a better question ;-) (just tell us the error message as per my comment), but the fact of the matter is that CF's implementation of struct-literal (and array-literal) notation has been blighted by a long list of implementation bugs.  I think they have finally been ironed out in CF10.

So, to answer your question slightly obliquely: "what's going on?" Shonky coding in ColdFusion is going on.

What's the fix? When you encounter these problems, use traditional struct notation instead (dot notation or associative array notation).

There's nowt better to do about it other than that, I'm afraid.

Also look in the [bug base](https://bugbase.adobe.com/) to see if your particular case has already been logged, and if not: log a new bug.